# Executable not running

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation, runtime-error

I have the following code:

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<string.h>
# define M 5 

void mycopy(char* text)
{
     char buffer[M];
     strcpy(buffer, text);
}

int main()
{
    char *name = "Kshitij";
    int i = 0;
    mycopy(name);
    printf("i = %d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles in GCC on Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1).
However, when I try to run the corresponding executable, I get a process `abort` output such as:

```
[1]    PID abort     ./executable.out
```

I understand that an error is expected since the size of `buffer` array is less than the length of `text` argument being passed to it in this case. However, I am unable to understand to grasp the concept behind this behavior. Why isn't a compile-time error stating the reason raised by the compiler here ?

Comment: C compiler does  not evaluate/trigger out of bounds errors on arrays. Runtime your code invokes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In your case you are probably corrupting the stack and return to main fails.

Comment: If you don't want to worry about such details when programming then you should probably pick a language other than C.

Comment: You’re saying the compiler should detect that you’re `strcpy`ing into a buffer of size 5 in `mycopy` from a parameter and tell you when you pass a parameter that’s a variable that contains a pointer to a string literal that’s bigger than that and warn? I guess that’s possible. It’s not really useful often enough to exist, though.

Comment: Study the difference between compile time error and run time error. I think some of the advance compilers might provide this case as warnings when warning level is kept high but in general this is not any syntactical error from C compiler perspective.

Comment: @LPs Thanks for sharing about "undefined behavior". I was never introduced to it in my primary coding classes.

Comment: @PaulR Thank you for your suggestion. I appreciate your concern and love for C language. I want to worry about these details, hence I willed to ask this question on SO. All I am asking is the concept behind getting this error and the reason why is it not a compile-time error but a runtime error.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, that's what exactly I am suggesting. I always had a hard time differentiating between compile-time and runtime errors. Moreover, I believe this a case of "undefined behavior" which got me all messed up in my head.

Comment: @prashanthns Thanks for your input.

Comment: The space in `# include` and `# define` is at least very unusual.

Comment: Because the compiler can't tell that it is a bug, or it simply doesn't care. There is no requirement from the C standard that the compiler must raise a diagnostic upon encountering this code. The whole responsibility of the bounds-checking falls on the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The C11 standard says the following in [7.1.4. Use of  library functions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4):

> If a function argument is described as being an array, *the pointer actually passed to the function **shall** have a value such that ***all* address computations and accesses to objects (that would be valid if the pointer did point to the first element of such an array) are in fact valid.**

And of [`strcpy`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.3)

> 2 The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including the terminating null character) into the **array pointed to by s1.**

And in [Appendix J.2 Undefined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2):

> 1 The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances: 
>   The pointer passed to a library function array parameter does not have a value such that all address computations and object accesses are valid (7.1.4).

Since the behaviour is undefined, according to standard, anything can happen. A compiler is actually *allowed* to do compile-time bounds checking, and the compilation might very well be aborted if it can be deduced that the program always writes out of bounds. Or the implementation can support range checking and abort with clear diagnostics. Or the `strcpy` might just copy the 4 first characters and add a terminating null, or copy `42` into the target string instead - and all these implementations would be standard-conforming.